# Core Data Updating Multiple Objects by Mistake

Tags: swift, swiftui, nsmanagedobject

For context, know that I am completely new to Swift, SwiftUI, Core Data, and event object-oriented programming.  I'm writing an iOS app as a means of trying to learn these frameworks.

I'm writing a basic gym tracking app.  My core data model has 3 entities:
Exercise, with properties for exerciseName and exerciseNotes, and 1-1 relationships to MuscleGroup and Type.

Type, with property typeName, and 1-Many relationship to Exercise

MuscleGroup, with property muscleGroupName, and 1-Many relationship to Exercise

I'm using NavigationView to start with a list of all exercises, and NavigationLink to access a detail view that is form for editing the existing list items.

In the detail view, I have TextFields for exerciseName and exerciseNotes, and a picker for muscleGroupName that is populated by a constant array of the available choices, and defaults the selection to the value of whatever object was selected from the list.

Anyway, when I edit exerciseName or exerciseNotes, the change goes through just fine.  If I edit the muscleGroup relationship (exercise.exerciseToMuscleGroup.muscleGroupName), the change does save to core data, but it seems to be updating the relationship for every object in the Exercise entity that had the same value for exercise.exerciseToMuscleGroup.muscleGroupName.  For example, if I have 3 exercises:
- Leg Press (Muscle Group Name = Legs)
- Bicep Curl (Muscle Group Name = Arms)
- Chest Press (Muscle Group Name = Chest)

With that, if I go in and edit Bicep Curl and change Muscle Group Name to Legs, that's fine - it works.  If I go back in to Bicep Curl and change Muscle Group Name back to Arms, it also sets the Leg Press Muscle Group Name to Arms, so now both Leg Press and Bicep Curl have "Arms" for exercise.exerciseToMuscleGroup.muscleGroupName.  If I change Chest Press to Muscle Group = Arms, again it works, but now if I change the Muscle Group on any of the 3 exercises, they ALL update with the new muscle group.

I would appreciate any guidance on how to get this right, so that only the instance of Exercise that is in the detail view is updated.

```
//
//  StrengthExerciseDetail.swift


import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct StrengthExerciseDetail: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
    let exercise: Exercise

    @State private var notes: String
    @State private var name: String
    @State private var muscleGroupName: String
    @State private var muscleGroupIndex: Int = 0
    let muscleGroupNames: [String] = ["Abdominals", "Arms", "Back", "Chest", "Legs", "Shoulders"]

    init(exercise: Exercise) {
        self.exercise = exercise
        // Define the initial form field values
        _notes = .init(initialValue: exercise.wrappedExerciseNotes)
        _name = .init(initialValue: exercise.wrappedExerciseName)
        _muscleGroupName = .init(initialValue: exercise.exerciseToMuscleGroup!.wrappedMuscleGroupName)

        // Set the Muscle Group picker selection
        var currentIndex: Int = 0
        for muscle in muscleGroupNames {
            if muscle == muscleGroupName {
                _muscleGroupIndex = .init(initialValue: currentIndex)
            } else {
                currentIndex += 1
            }
        }
        currentIndex = 0
    }

    func updateExercise(_ exercise: Exercise) {
        print("running update exercise")

        do {
            print("running loop")
            let newMuscleGroupName = muscleGroupNames[muscleGroupIndex]

            exercise.setValue(name, forKey: "exerciseName")
            exercise.setValue(notes, forKey: "exerciseNotes")
            exercise.setValue(newMuscleGroupName, forKeyPath: "exerciseToMuscleGroup.muscleGroupName")
            try moc.save()
            moc.refreshAllObjects()


        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
        moc.reset()
    }

    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Section(header: Text("Exercise Name")) {
                    TextField("Name", text: $name)
            }
            Section(header: Text("Muscle Group")) {
                Picker(selection: $muscleGroupIndex, label: Text("")) {
                    ForEach(0 ..< muscleGroupNames.count) {
                        Text(self.muscleGroupNames[$0])
                    }
                }
            }
            Section(header: Text("Notes")) {
                TextField("Notes", text: $notes)
                    .frame(height: 300.0)
            }
            Button("Save Changes") {
                self.updateExercise(self.exercise)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct StrengthExerciseDetail_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static let moc = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .mainQueueConcurrencyType)

    static var previews: some View {
        let exercise = Exercise(context: moc)
        exercise.exerciseName = "Booty Bounce"
        exercise.exerciseNotes = "This is a great strength builder"
        exercise.exerciseToMuscleGroup = MuscleGroup(context: moc)
        exercise.exerciseToMuscleGroup?.muscleGroupName = "Legs"
        exercise.exerciseToType = Type(context: moc)
        exercise.exerciseToType?.typeName = "Strength"

        return NavigationView {
            StrengthExerciseDetail(exercise: exercise)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not getting why you are fetching the Exercise in updateExercise again ? Why not only update the existing one. Also predicates on an editable name is not really a good idea.

Comment: @MarcT. because I don't know what I'm doing :)  Can you expand a bit on where you think I went wrong?

Comment: @MarcT. OK I see it now.  When I originally wrote the func, I was only passing in the exerciseName and then using that for fetch.  I later changed the code to pass the entire Exercise object, but I just didn't see how the fetch was now useless.  I updated the code to comment out the FetchRequest, and changed all the exerciseUpdate's to just exercise.  This functions, but I still have the same relationship problem, where any change to the relationship seems to update all relationships that had that same value.  Thanks for pointing this out to me.

Comment: Your issue is that you are setting the muscleGroupName of the muscleGroup and not the relation itself. Also I would not recommend to use the old style keypath way to refer to attributes or relation.

Comment: That makes perfect sense!  Now, I just have to figure out how to update the relationship itself.  Currently looking at mutableSetValueForKey as possible fix...

Comment: If you have a 1-1 relationship you only need to make something like this: exercise. muscleGroup = selectedMuscleGroup

Comment: Yes!  That was it!  Thanks @MarcT. !!